# difference between lamp instance and traditional php web app on google-app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

there is a new stuff added by google-app-engine: adding lamp instance one click
so, I want to know if this instance can be scalable and what is more efficient for php web app : lamp instance or traditional VMs vm for apache/php + cloud sql(mysql)+cloud storage

Comment: its not appengine, its gcp. those you would need to scale manually thats the difference vs appengine php

Comment: ok thank you  for your answer